# Why reducing agriculture subsidy reduce the unemployment?

Tags: democracy-3

When I move the cursor to reduce the agriculture subsidy, it say's that it will reduce the unemployment. This doesn't make sence to me. Who can explain?

Answer (score 3):

Agriculture is labor intensive, so increasing subsidy increases jobs, which reduces unemployment. Lack of profitability for agriculture could be construed as the reason why people move to urban areas looking for jobs, so making it profitable reduces unemployment.

Don't think too much about what the sliders means, they're just modeling the general cause and effect of the policies, not necessarily always accurately or in a manner you agree with.